# IBM informix ODBC driver to OLEDB

Tags: odbc, azure-data-factory, oledb, informix, dsn

We are doing a lift and shift of SSIS package through ADF. In this package, there is a connection between IBM Informix ODBC (DSN) to SQLDB(OLEDB). While we are migrating it through ADF, we see a issue with DSN, so tried creating a Connection string for DSN and we are using below connection string.
Driver={IBM INFORMIX 3.82 32 BIT};Host=xxxxx;Server=xxxxx;Service=1528;Protocol=olsoctcp;Database=d7main;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxxx;DB_LOCALE=en_US.819;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.819;UNICODE=TRUE;
But there is issue in connection with the above connection string. "The error is Infoxmix ODBC connection string is asking for OLEDB provider."

Comment: [This documentation](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) specifies a `Provider=` keyword. Have you tried using it?

Comment: If you want to use OLEDB te connection should be something like:
'Provider=Ifxoledbc.2;Data Source=stores7@dubi1170fc3;Persist Security Info=True;Password=xxxx;User ID=xxxxxx'

For ODBC the one you have is valid, but I suggest to upgrade to some newer. 3.82 is way too old (~20 years)

Comment: @jsagrera this error is popping up when I use the mentioned connection string for ODBC while loading the tables.

Comment: It's been a while since I played with SSIS, but I think it wants an OLEDB provider. You can either use the Informix OLEDB provider (with the string I mentioned before) or use the Microsoft OLEDB Provider for ODBC drivers (and give them an ODBC connection string) 
Something like `Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=myIfxDSN`  or with the full ODBC attributes

Comment: Haven't test it, but should be something like: `"Provider=MSDASQL;DRIVER={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER};SRVR=dubi1170fc3;DB=stores7;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;DLOC=en_US.819;CLOC=en_us.819;SERV=9095;PRO=onsoctcp;HOST=irk"` 

Driver name and so on depends on what you are using.
The 'MSDASQL'  is the 'Microsoft OleDB Provider for ODBC drivers'. The bridge that allows you to use an ODBC driver from an OLEDB client.

Comment: This provider is not working for my connection string.

Comment: Hello, please I need a immediate help on this. Please someone help me with this.

Comment: Then please contact your Informix Technical Support channels.  SO is not for urgent issues.

Comment: Hello can anyone, please help me on this.